# Can I pass a value to a page without using query strings or sessions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have created a web application in which there are two menus which load the same page. I need to check a condition in the page so that I can load different data based on the variable passed to this page. However, I don’t want to use a query string, since that would require using a different URL, which would interfere with SEO.

Is there a way to do this without using query strings or session data? I need to pass different values on clicking different links in the master page.

Comment: the reason i need to avoid query string is that these url has been used by seo team and are indexed by google so adding a query string may cause url mismatch problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the reference in the PreviousPage  property, you can search for controls on the source page and extract their value. You typically do this with the FindControl  method.

use PreviousPage.FindControl("yourcontrolname")

these link may help you

[How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

[PreviousPage Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [javascript to post data to you page](http://mentaljetsam.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/using-javascript-to-post-data-between-pages/) or you can use hidden fields or cookies

Answer (score 1):

Along with the two other answers if the URL is of concern with query string parameters (and you dont want sessions - eg due to in-proc storage), then one alternative to increase your rank with web-crawlers is [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Comment: thank you..i dont have any idea regarding that .. will have a look at it now

Answer (score 0):

you can pass values in many ways. using sessions, cookies, query string, hidden inputs. 
i personally feel storing query string for menu navigation its not problem, until unless he comes to know exact querystring parameters.

you can try this other methods, 
[Passing  Values between webforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

Comment: @Ravi- its a client requirement that there should be no change in url so querystring should not be used..may be i should try hidden inputs..thanks for your feed back

Answer (score 0):

Try window.location.hash: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

You could store data after the # in a URL.  This is what Twitter does.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem with query string is just url changing, you can use post method to send data with using a hidden input. like this:

```
<form  action="products.aspx" method="post">
...
<input type="hidden" id="field1" value="value1"/>
</form>
```

Or use ajax. You can send http request by means of javascript with ajax. In this case there are no url changing or something. This is an  example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; //changing the menu
    }
  }
params="field1="+document.getElementById("field1").value;
xmlhttp.open("POST","products.aspx",true);
xmlhttp.send(params);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [canonical links.](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394)

Using this, you can have two different URL forms, for example bob.aspx and bob.aspx?input=whatever and search engines will only include one of them (e.g. the first) in its index.